# MomentJS India's 5 + half-hour

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I was wondering how can I pre-define India's timezone while it's containing a half-hour +5:30 ?

I was trying to add one myself since I couldn't find any example that doesn't contain a round hour under: http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/ by couldn't find one, so instead I'm doing this:

```
moment.tz.add({
            "zones": {
                "IST": [
                    "+5 - IST"
                ],
.... });

var now = "2014-03-10 10:00";
    now = moment(now).tz("IST"); // adjusting my localized "now" to IST

if ( tz == "IST" )  now.add("minutes", 30);
```

But I still want to predefine my "+5" with a half-hour and remove the "IF" - how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me(copied straight from the [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/)):

```
moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "Asia/Kolkata": [
            "5:53:28 - LMT 1880 5:53:28",
            "5:53:20 - HMT 1941_9 5:53:20",
            "6:30 - BURT 1942_4_15 6:30",
            "5:30 - IST 1942_8 5:30",
            "6:30 - IST 1945_9_15 6:30",
            "5:30 - IST"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {},
    "links": {}
});
```